# Multiple Image SVG file in Umbraco Media Type

Tags: svg, png, jpeg, umbraco, opacitymask

I'm pretty good at Razor/MVC, but very new to Umbraco. I have a source design that contains a Jpeg and a Greyscale PNG wrapped up in an SVG such that I can have transparent background images in far less memory than usual.

Just wondering how I can set up a Media Type in Umbraco that places the SVG file, and the supporting bitmaps into the same folder.

I've tried creating a new media type with 3 upload slots, and it creates the new type as a folder type, but when I look in my folder /media/1071, it only contains the SVG.

Is there a way to get Umbraco to upload all 3 files to the same folder so that the SVG file can find the supporting files?

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the proper approach in Umbraco, but I did manage to get my transparent JPeg type thing working.

Instead of making a new Media Type, I've made a new document type. I have also made a default template for the document type.

By adding two media picker properties to the document type, and setting the Content-Type to "image/svg+xml" in the template, I'm able to generate the appropriate SVG file on the fly from the template.

So here's the template that works with my new DocType.

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = null;

    UmbracoContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/svg+xml";  

    var colourLayer = Umbraco.Media(Umbraco.Field("colourLayer").ToString());
    var maskLayer = Umbraco.Media(Umbraco.Field("maskLayer").ToString());
}<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 @colourLayer.umbracoWidth @colourLayer.umbracoHeight" enable-background="new 0 0 @colourLayer.umbracoWidth @colourLayer.umbracoHeight" xml:space="preserve">
  <image overflow="visible" width="@colourLayer.umbracoWidth" height="@colourLayer.umbracoHeight" mask="url(#imgmask)" xlink:href="@colourLayer.umbracoFile" />
  <mask id="imgmask">
    <image overflow="visible" width="@colourLayer.umbracoWidth" height="@colourLayer.umbracoHeight" xlink:href="@maskLayer.umbracoFile" />
  </mask>
</svg>
```

Please let me know if this is not how things are done in Umbraco. I much prefer to work with a system vs. against it.